# Visual Studio 2022, 2019 Community Edition: can not be installed

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition on my Windows10 notebook.

Unfortunately it always run into an error during the install phase.

I have tried the *usual* things:

- reboot
- shutdown the power on
- repair
- clean reinstall

Nothing helped so far, it always fail at the same exact point:

[image]

Details from the log:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=17.1.32113.165' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1310
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=17.1.32113.165\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  PIDKEY="NGKBDRWKQFTT82MTRMPKRM6XM"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"  FEEDBACKOPTIN="1" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
        Message Id: 1310
        Message Details: Error writing to file: stdole.dll.   Verify that you have access to that directory.
```

*To that directory*: which exactly?

My system is brand new Windows10, just have installed a few weeks ago.

I've administrator rights on my computer and I granted Installer to modify the system.

I have selected *.NET Desktop development* and clicked on install button. Haven't changed any preferences or install destination.

[image]

I also tried to install an earlier version with 2019 Community Edition, but it fails at the exact same point with same error.

I found someone with the same error but no solution has been provided: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/packageidmicrosoftvisualstudiominshellinteropmsipa-16/346774

Indeed, when manually starting this particular *msi*:

[image]

But I don't have "Run as administrator" if I right-click on that:

[image]

Comment: then it's probably some issue on your system. Millions of developers already installed it and has no problem. What did you choose to install in the first time?

Comment: I would do a full uninstall and reinstall. VS2022 installer is the most advanced and simplest to customize installer Microsoft has, in order to help, we need to know more about the solution in question

Comment: A full legal version Microsoft Office 2021 Pro might cause this? Referenced slightly from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695533/whats-the-difference-between-stdole-dll-in-the-gac-vs-microsofts-nuget-packag

Comment: Brave close voters: how about proposing a *solution* instead clicking on close button?

Comment: I've never installed MS Office in my recent personal laptops and all of them can install VS 2015/2017/2019/2022 without any issues, and my work laptops of course also have various Office version and no problem whatsoever. Try backup data and do a factory reset for Windows 10

Comment: Windows Update was causing this. It corrupted my whole Win10, so after trying to fix it with a recommendation on an accapted answer on official MS pages (by an official MS advisor) my PC can't be started anymore. So I had to do a clean reinstall with losing all installed apps, and now it's working fine. But I lost a whole day with this. Congrats to MS again by planning updates this nice way.. (computer installed 2wks ago, it had power and network access since then without any interruption, but MS still managed to corrupt it).